# How does one populate a structure using multiple select statements

Tags: c#, sql, structure

**Objective:** Populate a structure using multiple select statements, using C# and SqlServer2005

**Issue:** Currently I can populate a structure using one select statement, but due to the nature of this particular select statement, to generate the correct results the query needs to be broken down and hence I have to use multiple selects to populate one structure. Is this possible or am I going about it the wrong way. Below is the code I am using

```
public static bool GetColumns()
{
    String sql = "";

    try
    {
       conn.Open();

       sql = @"SELECT
                   database.dbo.table1.column1
               FROM
                   database.dbo.table1;

              SELECT
                   database.dbo.table2.column2
              FROM
                   database.dbo.table2;

              SELECT
                   database.dbo.table3.column3
              FROM    
                  database.dbo.table3 ;" ;

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

         MyStructure struct1 = new MyStructure();   

         while (dr.Read())
        {
           struct1.column1 = dr.GetValue(0);
           struct1.column2 = dr.GetValue(1);
           struct1.column3 = dr.GetValue(2);

          MyArrayList.Add(struct1);
        }

           dr.Close();

           conn.Close();

        return true;
 }

 catch (Exception ex)
 {
    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        conn.Close();

    error.LogError(ex, "", "")
    return false
 }
```

The code above does not work because the values I am listing our out of the bounds of each individual select statement. What is the correct way?

Comment: Write MyStructure struct1 = new MyStructure(); before assigning values to it, not afterwards. That is, put this line right below while(dr.Read()).

Comment: thank you, my original code wasn't written that way. Just an error in copying over

Comment: If the number of columns is 3 (or more), your code should work. Perhaps there are some nulls coming in: set up a heading condition skipping if dr == null. Also you can rely on dr[index] and perform a Cast to the target Type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your statement will return multiple result sets, If you are using DataReader, then you will get multiple results. Use [`DataReader.NextResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatablereader.nextresult.aspx) method to get next result set and show data accordingly.

If you are not concerned about `DataReader` then you can use `DataSet` and use a `DataAdapater` to fill out the results in multiple `DataTables` inside the DataSet.

Comment: The term _connection oriented data access_ is misleading. What do you mean by that? `DataAdapter.Fill` also uses a connection and a `DataReader`.

Comment: so instead of dr.GetValue use dr.NextResult or do I only invoke NextResult after the GetValue for each respective query?

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I meant, DataReader will keep the connection open until reading is done. Remember it reading it somewhere.. may be from here http://csharp.net-informations.com/ado.net/ado.net-data-access-architecture.htm

Comment: @TristanDescartes, see here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-3

Comment: @Habib: It's the method `Fill` which decides at the end whether or not the connection will be closed according to the state of the connection at the beginning. If it was open it stays open, it it was closed it will be closed.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I didn't know that fill would keep the connection open if it was previously in open state. Thanks. I will modify my answer.

Comment: @Habib thank you again, as I am new to C# I did a little research on NextResult and found this helpful [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311274)